# list view retrieve one item from real time database in firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve all the data in fire-base on a list view, but it adds only the first item on the list view. Once I add a new student it will retrieve only the last new student to the list view.
I have searched a lot over the internet but I did not get the needed solution. Please can you help me in this?

[image: My Fire-base Data]

Here is my class which adds the required data to the list view.

```
public class emptySeatNum extends Activity {

ListView listView;
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference reference;

ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

Students students;
String studentName;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.seat_num);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.newListView);
    students = new Students();
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    reference = database.getReference("Students");
    studentName = students.getStuden_name();

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                students = ds.getValue(Students.class);

                array.add(students.getStuden_name());
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(emptySeatNum.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);

                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: add this `ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();` inside `onDataChange`

Comment: @PeterHaddad the same!! if I put the arraylist inside the for loop it will return only the last item of the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is  because you are everytime adding below 2 lines in the **`for`** loop,which is making the adapter everytime and setting it.

```
adapter=newArrayAdapter<String(emptySeatNum.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Place them outside the **`for`** loop and then run it.

```
 public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                students = ds.getValue(Students.class);    
                array.add(students.getStuden_name());
            }//for loop ending brace
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(emptySeatNum.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

Comment: I have already tried to do the same solution that you just recommended and I tried it again but it gives the same results!